How to make my Binarizer class pickle friendly? (inheriting torch.autograd.function)
I have this class that I use inside my RNN to binarize a series of masks that I'm learning on my GRU. However, when I try to save my checkpoints using pickle, I always get an error stating that this object  cannot be pickled. Does anybody know what is the problem?
class Binarizer(torch.autograd.Function):
        """Binarizes {0, 1} a real-valued tensor."""
    
        @staticmethod
        def forward(ctx, inputs, threshold=5e-3):
            outputs = inputs.clone()
            outputs[inputs <= threshold] = 0
            outputs[inputs > threshold] = 1
            return outputs
    
        @staticmethod
        def backward(ctx, grad_output):
            return grad_output, None 


Did you try writing it as a nn.Module?

Cannot reproduce: Saving a model that uses your binarizer like so works without an error for me (using PyTorch 2.4.0). Can you specify what doesn't work for you? In particular, can you share a minimal reproducible example?

I just realized that I should have used torch.save(model.state_dict(), "test.pth") in my shared code. But that is working just as well.

I haven't tried writing it as a nn.module yet, will try later.
Even if I use torch.save instead of pickle.dumps I get the same "cannot pickle binarizer object" (python 3.9.4)

Please provide a minimal reproducible example: What exact code are you using for saving? The code you share should enable others to run it and reproduce your issue with minimum work (i.e. copy-paste and run without adaptations other than, say, the file path for saving). Otherwise it is really hard to assess what is going wrong with your code.

I solved it, in my GRU class, compared to @simon 's code, i was saving to self.binarizer = Binarizer() instead of Binarizer.apply. The suggestion to write it as nn.module was also correct.
